# Верное ли оформление перевода в скобках в учебниках?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, курсив

В одном нашел это:

**Некоторые считают, что оно произошло от латинского *relegere*, что означает «связывать», «соединять»**.

То, что меня тут интересует:

1. А разве нужно выделять латинские буквы курсивом? В подобных случаях всегда переводимое слово выделяется курсивом?
2. А кавычки разве не должны быть общими, т. е.: *...«связывать, соединять»*? Или можно и так и так?

Второй пример из другого учебника:

**На рассмотренном физическом явлении основано действие *электроскопа* (от греч. *электрон* и *скопео* — наблюдать, обнаруживать)**.

Интересующее:

1. Курсив может быть общим (т. е.: **...*электрон и скопео***)?
2. Первые слова, переводимые, всегда выделяются именно курсивом? А кавычки не запрещены?
3. Почему не закавычено *наблюдать, обнаруживать*?